# transform :translateY(-50%) not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I decided to learn flexbox so I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf_DjL_dbug&t=3382s) and now I'm stuck. I did everything step by step, and when it comes to styling in CSS ( 50:40 min of video - after adding transform: translateY(-50%); ) all h2 elements going up instead of stay center.

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300');
    * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html, body {
     height: 100%;
     background: #FFF;
     text-align: center;
     font: 1.15em/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     color: #FFF;
    }
    .wrapper {
     background-color: #F5F5F5;
     height: 100%;
    }
    #header {
     background-color: #AFDED4;
    }
    .logo {
     padding: 2%;
    }
    img {
     max-width: 100%;
    }
    h2.dark {
     color: #34495E;
    }
    h2 {
     font: 300 2em/1 'Raleway', sans-serif;
     color: #FFF;
     padding: 2%;
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="row" id="header">
      <div class="col-12">
       <img class="logo" src="img/flexy-logo.png"/>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
       <nav role="navigation" id="nav">
        <input class="trigger" type="checkbox" id="mainNavButton">
        <label for="mainNavButton" onclick>Menu</label>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
       <img src="img/kite.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12" style="padding: 2%;">
       <h2 class="dark">Welcome to Flexy!</h2>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #3C8BB6; padding: 5% 0 3%;">
      <div class="col-12">
       <img src="img/paper.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #F6931E;">
      <div class="col-11">
       <h2>Get ready for take off!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
       <img class="circle" src="img/take-off.png">
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="row" style="background-color: #1ABC9C;">
      <div class="col-11">
       <h2>We're flying around the globe.</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
       <img class="circle" src="img/orange-globe.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #E5EF3F;">
      <div class="col-11">
       <h2 class="dark">Above the clouds &amp; over the sea.</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
       <img class="circle" src="img/waves.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #34495E;">
      <div class="col-11">
       <h2>In just 42 hours and 27 minutes.</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
       <img class="circle" src="img/plane.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #00AFE1;">
      <div class="col-11">
       <h2>So come along for the ride!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
       <img class="circle" src="img/paper-blue.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
       <img src="img/plane-background.png">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #66D4FF;">
      <div class="col-12">
       <h2>Follow Us</h2>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #66D4FF;">
      <div class="col-12">
       <ul class="social">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="background-color: #34495E; border-top: 2px solid 
     #F6931E">
      <div class="col-12">
       <p>&copy; Flexy.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div> <!---End Wrapper--->
```

I don't know what I did wrong. Just followed intructions mentioned in video. Anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: `translateY(-50%)` means moving up by 50%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person in the video makes a mistake. He wrote down `tranform` instead of `transform`. His code never applied. I fast forward the entire video to see if he fixes it somewhere, and he doesn't. `translate(-50%)` only moves up by 50%. I think the code looks fine without it!

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Yes, it looks like he made a mistake I didn't notice that. For a moment I thought it was my fault